# Java SE preventing maven clean

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, build

I am using [maven remote resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/) which basically copies some resources from one module of my app to another and creates an xml file with the list of copied files. A lot of times when I build my app and deploy it to tomcat, then terminate it and try to do it again, the build fails with the following message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean 
(default-clean) on project students-ui: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete 
{Application-path}\target\classes\META-INF\maven\remote-resources.xml -> [Help 1]
```

This happens randomly, sometimes doesn't happen at all and sometimes takes 5 - 10 tries to go through.
When it happens and I try to delete the file manually it says that it is in use by Java SE. Why does Java hold up to this file?

Comment: Typical Windows problem. Close all applications (Eclipse, File Explorer) check for running virus applications etc. Can not be solved by Maven nor by any plugin.The problem is that windows open files in exclusive mode which blocks other access. Running from console? Or from Eclipse?

Comment: I am running from console. So there is no other way of fixing it? If i close eclipse and other related applications it will take even more time to build, deploy, check if everything's as i wanted, terminate, do changes and rebuild. It's the same file being used everytime.

Comment: Yes i know. The problem is related to Windows. If you have Eclipse open some files are accessed by Eclipse which means from Windows point of view locked...which means you usually can't delete them from console as you see. What you might try is to use from the root of your build: `mvn -pl projectToBuild clean package` ...which reduces the time...On the other hand the question is if you really need to run build on console?

Comment: You can use [FileMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) to see which process accesses the file and for what reasons.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the claim "windows open files in exclusive mode" is utter, made-up nonsense. Its entirely up to the application to open files in shared mode (or not) so this is very likely an ECLIPSE problem. Many java-programmers simply dont know how windows works - this is also true for all of the eclipse contributors; they will take the very first solution to their problem, which apparently was "exclusive mode" because thats also the WINAPI default parameter.

Comment: In my case closing all open files on eclipse solved the issue.